# My build doesn't transpile correctly the source

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

My nodejs server render a blank page instead of my react app.
In the inspector I can see it display my `index.html` but there is this error in the console

`'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' main.12045785.chunck.js`

I guess it's a problem during the transpiling because when I open this file `main.12045785.chunck.js` in VSC all the text is grey, but when I open a chunck file from another react project it has the javascript syntax color.

my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myqpp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.8.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.6",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt": "0.4.14",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.3.1",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.2.0",
    "react-country-region-selector": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^7.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.7.2",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.7.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-sidebar": "^3.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

my `webpack.config.js`

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const safePostCssParser = require('postcss-safe-parser');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');

const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  const publicPath = isEnvProduction
    ? paths.servedPath
    : isEnvDevelopment && '/';
  const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';

  const publicUrl = isEnvProduction
    ? publicPath.slice(0, -1)
    : isEnvDevelopment && '';
  const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: Object.assign(
          {},
          shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: '../../' } : undefined
        ),
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {

        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 3,
            }),
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
        options: {
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      });
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: [
      client:
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
      paths.appIndexJs,
    ].filter(Boolean),
    output: {
      path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
      publicPath: publicPath,
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? info =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')),
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {
              ecma: 8,
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,
              inline: 2,
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true,
            },
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,
              ascii_only: true,
            },
          },
          parallel: true,
          cache: true,
          sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {
            parser: safePostCssParser,
            map: shouldUseSourceMap
              ? {

                  inline: false,
                  annotation: true,
                }
              : false,
          },
        }),
      ],
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        name: false,
      },
      runtimeChunk: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: ['node_modules'].concat(
        process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
      ),
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
      },
      plugins: [
        PnpWebpackPlugin,
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
      ],
    },
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [
        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
        {
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

              },
              loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
            },
          ],
          include: paths.appSrc,
        },
        {
          oneOf: [
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),

                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent:
                            '@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: isEnvProduction,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: isEnvProduction,.
                sourceMaps: false,
              },
            },
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              }),
            },
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: true,
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true,
                },
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),
      isEnvProduction &&
        shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
        new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime~.+[.]js/]),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),

      isEnvDevelopment && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
      isEnvProduction &&
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
          chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
        }),
      new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
        publicPath: publicPath,
      }),
isEnvProduction &&
        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
          clientsClaim: true,
          exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
          importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn',
          navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
          navigateFallbackBlacklist: [
            new RegExp('^/_'),
            new RegExp('/[^/]+\\.[^/]+$'),
          ],
        }),
      useTypeScript &&
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
          typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
            basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
          }),
          async: false,
          checkSyntacticErrors: true,
          tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
          compilerOptions: {
            module: 'esnext',
            moduleResolution: 'node',
            resolveJsonModule: true,
            isolatedModules: true,
            noEmit: true,
            jsx: 'preserve',
          },
          reportFiles: [
            '**',
            '!**/*.json',
            '!**/__tests__/**',
            '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
            '!**/src/setupProxy.*',
            '!**/src/setupTests.*',
          ],
          watch: paths.appSrc,
          silent: true,
          formatter: typescriptFormatter,
        }),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    node: {
      dgram: 'empty',
      fs: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      child_process: 'empty',
    },
    performance: false,
  };
};
```

I don't know if the problem is because i'm using `.jsx` files but I'm sure my webpack configuration is transpiling them correctly.

Any ideas ?

Comment: can you show us the content of your main entry file? From what you say, this can simply be a common syntax error. Try reviewing your code

Comment: How can I show you the content the file is so big ? If it was a common syntax error why I can compile then ?

Comment: I*m still struggle with this any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

#### I think It's because html 5 routing

add `<base href="/" />` into the `<head>` of my `index.html`

*or if that doesn't work try*

add a **slash** to your script src: `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: I found this solutions on internet too but both didn't work, I don't think I have a problem with the routing but more with the transpiling.